# Cannot process flags argument with a Regex pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am new to Python and new to Regex so please forgive me if this is an obvious question. I am using Python 3.10 and have written a function with the purpose of iterating through a directory provided by the user. It will go through all subdirectories looking for XML files stored therein. The directory i am aiming at is the application data from a mobile device. I then wish to run a Regex search over the recovered XMLs looking for that are 32 alphanumeric characters in length and return only these lines.

when I run the code below i get the error
ValueError: cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern.

```
import os
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def xml_search(directory):
    xml_files = []
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".xml")
               xml_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    print("The following XML files have been found.")
    print(xml_files)

    for xml_file in xml_files:
        with open(xml_file, "r") as f:
             tree = ET.parse(f)
             root = tree.getroot()
             strings = []
             for string in root.iter():
                 strings.append(string)
                 regex = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-._]{32}$", re.I | re.M | re.S)
                 return_strings = re.findall(regex, strings, re.I | re.M | re.S)
                 print(return_strings)
```

The final print function is just to error check before moving on with functionality and will not be in the final code. My inclusion of the re.I | re.M | re.S is my attempt to troubleshoot the issue.

I have confirmed that the strings list is returning the parsed data from the XML files i just cannot get the regex search to run against it.

Comment: First question: Which line does the error come from?

Comment: I am guessing it comes from `re.findall(regex, strings, re.I | re.M | re.S)` and is trying to tell you that you already applied the flags when compiling the regex in the previous line, so here you should just call as `re.findall(regex, strings)` and the flags arg is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would move the `re.compile` call outside (before) the outer loop. But it appears that your problem is that you are passing to `re.findall` a list to be searched when this should be a string.

Because of this error and the fact that you have simplified your code (for example, I don't see where list `strings` will be used) I therefore can't be certain what you are trying to do exactly, but perhaps the following:

```py
import os
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def xml_search(directory):
    xml_files = []
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".xml"): # missing colon originally
               xml_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    print("The following XML files have been found.")
    print(xml_files)

    regex = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-._]{32}$", re.I | re.M | re.S)
    for xml_file in xml_files:
        with open(xml_file, "r") as f:
            tree = ET.parse(f)
            root = tree.getroot()
            strings = []
            return_strings = []
            for string in root.iter():
                strings.append(string)
                return_strings.extend(regex.findall(string))
            print(return_strings)
```